# Вывод прогресс бара на время блокировка диалогового окна

Tags: c++, qt

Заблокировал диалоговое окно с помощью метода:

```
QWidget::setEnabled(false);
```

Разблокирую по сигналу со второго потока:

```
QWidget::setEnabled(true);
```

Хочу выводить прогресс бар во время блокировки окна. Прогресс бар по верх диалогового окна. Чтобы не казалось что программа зависла. 
Как это сделать ? Версия qt4.7.8

Comment: Делаете модальное диалоговое окно с прогресс баром и запускаете - не должно быть ничего сложного

Comment: Посмотрите пример: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressdialog.html#details

Comment: если делать через модальный диалог, то блокировать не обязательно. диалог будет перехватывать фокус.